Unity high res mesh brighter than low res mesh despite using the same material
I'm currently making an LOD system for terrain. I have a high-res mesh:

And a low-res mesh:

As you can see, the high-res mesh is significantly brighter than the low-res mesh. They are definitely using the same material. Is there a fix for this?
I've got two global meshes: fast_mesh and subdiv_mesh. They are built like so:
public void build_fast_mesh() {
    int maxTriangleCount = 8*8*8*5;

    if (triangleBuffer != null) {
        triangleBuffer.Dispose();
        triCountBuffer.Dispose();
    }

    triangleBuffer = new ComputeBuffer (maxTriangleCount, sizeof (float) * 3 * 3, ComputeBufferType.Append);
    triCountBuffer = new ComputeBuffer (1, sizeof (int), ComputeBufferType.Raw);

    triangleBuffer.SetCounterValue (0);
    march_shader.SetTexture (0, "points", points);
    march_shader.SetBuffer (0, "triangles", triangleBuffer);
    march_shader.SetFloat ("scale", scale);
    march_shader.SetFloat ("isoLevel", isoLevel);

    march_shader.Dispatch (0, 1, 1, 1);
    ComputeBuffer.CopyCount (triangleBuffer, triCountBuffer, 0);
    int[] triCountArray = { 0 };
    triCountBuffer.GetData (triCountArray);
    int numTris = triCountArray[0];

    Triangle[] tris = new Triangle[numTris];
    triangleBuffer.GetData (tris, 0, 0, numTris);
    
    if (fast_mesh == null) {fast_mesh = new Mesh();}
    fast_mesh.Clear();
    if (numTris == 0) {return;}
    var vertices = new Vector3[numTris * 3];
    var meshTriangles = new int[numTris * 3];
    for (int i = 0; i < numTris; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            meshTriangles[i * 3 + j] = i * 3 + j;
            vertices[i * 3 + j] = tris[i][j];
        }
    }

    fast_mesh.vertices = vertices;
    fast_mesh.triangles = meshTriangles;

    fast_mesh.RecalculateNormals ();
    triCountBuffer.Dispose();
    triangleBuffer.Dispose();
}

public void build_subdiv_mesh() {
    create_subdivisions();
    combine_child_meshes();
    subdiv_mesh.RecalculateNormals();
    subdiv_mesh.UploadMeshData(false);
}

public void combine_child_meshes() {
    if (subdiv_mesh == null) {subdiv_mesh = new Mesh();}
    subdiv_mesh.Clear();
    MeshFilter[] meshFilters = GetComponentsInChildren<MeshFilter>(true).Where(mf => mf.sharedMesh != null).ToArray();
    CombineInstance[] combine = new CombineInstance[meshFilters.Length - 1];
    for (int i = 1; i < meshFilters.Length; i++)
    {
        combine[i-1].mesh = meshFilters[i].sharedMesh;
        combine[i-1].transform = meshFilters[i].transform.localToWorldMatrix * meshFilters[i].transform.parent.worldToLocalMatrix;

        meshFilters[i].gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    subdiv_mesh.CombineMeshes(combine);
}

create_subdivisions() is a function which creates sub-meshes. This is essentially the same as build_fast_mesh() but the scale component is smaller.
Edit: Fixed. I was executing this in edit mode which meant that the previous subdivision was being written on top of. There were multiple copies of this specific mesh in the same spot. That's what was making it incredibly bright.

How have you created these meshes? Is it possible that the normal vectors of one mesh are significantly different from the other?

I've created these meshes programmatically. Both of these meshes have .RecalculateNormals() called on them immediately after their triangles have been assigned.

What material are you using for them?

A standard Unity material (as you get it by right click -> create -> material) except the Albedo is set to dark green, the smoothness is set to 0 and the source is set to albedo alpha. Playing around with any of these variables doesn't change the difference in lighting.

Do you call UploadMeshData after RecalculateNormals? (Note that we would not have to ask these follow-up questions if your post included all the code and steps required to reproduce a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example - we could just follow the recipe ourselves and observe the results / use them to test proposed solutions)

I've added the code but this seems to me like a configuration issue (i.e. "You need to set lighting mode to X") rather than an implementation issue. UploadMeshData() doesn't remedy the problem.

I'm not aware of any configurations that would make Unity discriminate between two otherwise-similar meshes, which is why some quirk of how the meshes are authored is the first suspect. Is the mesh double-sided / is the material configured to render both sides? If so, it could be that in creating the subdivisions you're also accidentally inverting the triangles, causing the generated normals to point 180° opposite the corresponding normals from the other mesh. Hard to know without seeing the code for create_subdivisions

When you solve a problem, be sure to post your solution as an Answer by writing it in the "Your Answer" box below. Solutions should never be appended to question posts with an edit.
